# imshow(A, 2) : Invalid IMSHOW syntax

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm new in image processing with matlab, when i wrote this code :

```
A = [0 0 1 0 0; 0 1 1 1 0; 1 1 1 1 1; 0 1 1 1 0; 0 0 1 0 0];
B = [A A A A A; A A A A A; A A A A A; A A A A A; A A A A A];
imshow(A, 2)
imshow(B, 2)
```

I got this error :

```
Error using imshow>preParseInputs (line 439)
Invalid IMSHOW syntax.

Error in imshow (line 214)
  varargin_translated = preParseInputs(varargin{:});
```

Comment: What is the `2` supposed to do? Where is `B` used?

Comment: @beaker, I just added `imshow(B, 2)`, and for `2`, i think it's used to get a binary image

Comment: If you'd read the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imshow.html) you'd have seen that `2` is not correct syntax.

Comment: @Bilal The second parameter is not necessary at all. `imshow` will display binary, grayscale, color-mapped (mostly), or multi-channel images just fine.

Comment: @beaker, yeah ! you're right, i simply used  `imshow(A)` and it works fine, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The function `imshow()` is not deprecated at all and it does take a double matrix as a first input. However, the second input (the colormap) cannot be a scalar, it must be a matrix with 3 columns where each row specifies an RGB color value. By doing

```
A = [0 0 1 0 0; 0 1 1 1 0; 1 1 1 1 1; 0 1 1 1 0; 0 0 1 0 0];
imshow(A,[1 1 1])
```

a small all-white picture appears. It is up to you, now, to adjust the colormap that better suits your goals.

Comment: thank you for the replay, could you explain what `[1, 1, 1]` means here please ?

Comment: by setting `1` in all three components (red, green, blue) you have a pure white. That's why `A` is all white if you run this code.